# ActiveRecord model doesn't show timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

All ActiveRecord models in my Rails app recently showed a strange behavior relating to timestamps: The can be saved in the database (sqlite3 for development), but a loaded model only has 'nil' fields.

Saving:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "confirmed_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ?, "user_type_id" = ?     
WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["confirmed_at", "2014-06-07 13:50:27.437678"], ["updated_at", 
"2014-06-07 13:50:35.680003"], ["user_type_id", 1]]
```

Loading:

```
=> #<User id: 1 ... created_at: nil, updated_at: nil ... confirmed_at: nil, ...>
```

When directly accessing the database, I can see all timestamps in the 'saving'-format. Any suggestions?

Comment: What command do you use to save your row?

Comment: MODEL.save. But this behavior is also applied on third-party gems… It even happens, when I create a new model by MODEL.create.

Comment: @Niklas - what types are your db columns?

Comment: t.datetime and t.timestamps, which probably leads to datetime

Comment: I found the error! See my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior appears because of some settings I made at the very beginning. In `application.rb` I set the following:

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Berlin'
```

This causes a loading error as `active_record.default_timezone` can't be set like the application's `time_zone`. To prevent this, I updated my code:

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```